# ios MPMoviePlayerController playing video over window

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my iPad application, I want to have back ground animation all over app. So what I did is create the player object and adding it to window in app delegate. And then I made the background color of all the view controller's as clearColor. The following is the code that I wrote. But a small problem is that, my app works only in landscape. Using below code, its adding the video in portrait mode. How can I make it work in iOS 5 and iOS 6?

```
NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:VIDEO_FILE ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
self.bgPlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
self.bgPlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
[self.bgPlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 748)];

[self.window addSubview:self.bgPlayerController.view];
[self.window sendSubviewToBack:self.bgPlayerController.view];

[self.bgPlayerController play];
```

Also I want to make sure that when the orientation is changed between landscape right and left, the video must also rotate in the background.

Comment: You are adding the player directly onto a window and since a window does not have any orientation, it will not respect any changes automatically. You will have to rotate the view yourself if you insist on the given approach. Use the view's `transform` property to achieve that.

Comment: @Till, Is there any other way to handle the orientation on its own? I tried to create a category for MPMoviePlayerController, still it didnt' work.

Comment: The most simply way is putting MPMoviePlayerController's view onto a viewController's view that respects re/orientation. Anything else is pure pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any solution. After adding the video to window, i'm manually observing the orientations and rotating the orientation of video by coding.